# enumerating ipv4 and ipv6 address of my cards using boost asio

Tags: boost-asio, ipv6

I am trying to enumerate ipv4 and ipv6 addresses of all the network cards(I have 2 cards) my pc.

I am using the following code to do that.

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(),"");
    tcp::resolver::iterator it=resolver.resolve(query);

    while(it!=tcp::resolver::iterator())
    {
        boost::asio::ip::address addr=(it++)->endpoint().address();
        if(addr.is_v6())
        {
            std::cout<<"ipv6 address: ";
        }
        else
            std::cout<<"ipv4 address: ";

        std::cout<<addr.to_string()<<std::endl;

    }
```

The code displays correct ipv4 addresses but not ipv6. Here is the output

```
ipv6 address: ::1
ipv4 address: 192.168.10.200
ipv4 address: 192.168.10.236
```

I have very minimum knowledge of ipv6. When I list the information about network interface using ipconfig/all I see that the actual ipv6 addresses are

```
fe80::226:5aff:fe14:5687%5 
fe80::225:64ff:feb2:4f61%4
```

Can someone please guide me how to list the ipv6 addresses.
Thanks.

Comment: `fe80::` are link local scope addresses it is possible Boost only enumerates global scope addresses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the platform is Windows 7 SP1 the link-local interfaces are being skipped as they are tagged "*SkipAsSource*" by Windows which means that [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will not return them and hence neither will Boost.

You can try to inspect the flag with the following command:

```
netsh int ipv6 show addresses level=verbose

Address fe80::e0:0:0:0%14 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Scope Id           : 0.14
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Deprecated
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : **true**
```