# Boost ASIO - obtaining sorted endpoints (first IPv4 then IPv6)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

When boost asio (1.42) obtains endpoints it may contain both IPv4 and IPv6.

Is it possible to get endpoints sorted (first v4 then v6)?

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(host, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(port));
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end;

/* I WANT FIRST ENDPOINTS TO BE IPv4, THEN  IPv6 */
while (error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
    socket.close();
    socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can check the type and performance its not your priority or there are not too many endpoints, you can just do 2 whiles and in one just do the V4 and then other while for the v6. 
Something like

```
while (error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
 if(isv4(*endpoint_iterato)){
    socket.close();
    socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
 }
}


while (error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
   if(isv6(*endpoint_iterato)){
    socket.close();
    socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
   }
}
```

check this question for filters too

[enumerating ipv4 and ipv6 address of my cards using boost asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327210/enumerating-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-of-my-cards-using-boost-asio)