# boost::asio Get the ip address for a particular network device?

Tags: boost-asio

For example on OSX I'd like to be able to ask for en0, en1, etc.

I've found example code here which lets you iterate over all devices, but I can't see how to get the names for those, or to look up by name, in a cross-platform way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [enumerating ipv4 and ipv6 address of my cards using boost asio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327210/enumerating-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-of-my-cards-using-boost-asio)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure i understand your question. But when you say you have found a way to iterate over the devices you are looking for, i suppose you mean one of the iterators you get when resolving a query in boost?

If so, that iterates over a list of endpoints.
If you know the endpoints, you can get their addresses by just calling `some_endpoint.address()`. That returns a `boost::asio::ip::address` (or udp, if applicable, of course) and with that address you can interact in all kinds of ways: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address.html

I would guess `to_string()` is what you are looking for.

If that was not what you asked, disregard. ^^

edit:

If you mean you want to find out the device names on a remote host of which you have the address or endpoint, i cannot help you. And honestly i doubt that is easily possible using asio. I always assumed those names to be internal. And asio is already too far up the Osi stack to even find the devices MAC-address easily. I would assume you would need to log into the remote host and look up the names there using ifconfig or whatever that system uses, looking for the ip-addresses you found from the outside.

Then again, it might be possible, maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. On mac different services (wifi, ethernet, etc.) would have BSD device names like en0, en1, etc. On Linux the same, e.g. eth0. I imagine the same on windows. I'd like to be able to query a device by name, i.e. ask what is the ip address of en0?

Comment: Also I'm talking about the local host

Comment: Hmm, that is not really a functionality i would expect from boost::asio. You basically want to know what names your Os has assigned to certain devices on the machine. I do not know how to go about that. I only work on linux and if i needed something like that i would probably just look the name<->ip-address conversion up in ifconfig. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Boost.Asio, but other libraries, such as [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv), can be used to query a system for its network interfaces. [Here](http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/networking.html#network-interfaces) is an example from the libuv introduction.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use [getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html). There may be a similar function on OSX as the function is available on FreeBSD (and possible other BSD variants).

Comment: From the FreeBSD 5 man page: "The getifaddrs implementation first appeared in BSDi BSD/OS".